# How do i run a replace function in async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I had a MongoDB and I want to change a value of a bunch of templates.

I guess I get the variable and replace the old value.

```
  findTemplates.forEach(async templateName => {
     const template = await getTemplate( templateName )
     const templateBody = await replaceBody( template.body )
     templateBody.replace('string', 'another-string');
  })

  async function getTemplate (siteName) {
    const id = await emailTemplate.model.findOne({
      'name.de': siteName,
      language: 'en',
      businessUnit: '24ede462ad78fd0d4fd39dfa',
    }).distinct('_id')

    const body = await emailTemplate.model.findOne({
      '_id': id,
    }).distinct('body')

    return {
      id: id,
      body: body
    }
  }

  function replaceBody( body ) {
     return body.replace('one', 'two')
  }
```

unfortunately, I get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: body.replace is not a functiontemplateBodyHow can I use the replace function in my forEach async function?

Comment: You should add the code for `replaceBody` and `getTemplate`.

Comment: are you sure the error isn't `templateBody.replace is not a function`? your code never tries `body.replace` - unless of course the error is occurring in the unseen `replaceBody` function

Comment: @Bravo unless it's in `replaceBody`.

Comment: Indeed, @briosheje, but then why show this bit of code and not the code that throws the error?

Comment: Side note 1: Aside from the underlying problem, the code above uses an anti-pattern: If you pass an `async` function into something (like `forEach`) that doesn't do anything with the promise the function returns, you must handle errors locally. Or better yet: Don't do that.

Comment: @Bravo perhaps he thinks the error is there, though the TypeError clearly says that `body.replace` is not a function. So, unless he typed the error manually, I would rather believe that the copy-past procedure is actually more correct than expecting OP to have manually copied the error performing a typo :P

Comment: Side note 2: Assuming `templateBody` is a string, `replace` **returns** a new string with the replacement. Your existing code doesn't use that, making the `replace` call pointless.

Comment: as @Andy pointed out, OP should post code for `replaceBody()` function

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your sample, so I can simulate it, this sample works as you expected, but no exception was thrown. So, the only mistake I have detected was in this line:

```
 // You must not put await here because replace body does not return a Promise.
 const templateBody = replaceBody( template.body )
```

```js
const allTemplates = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  allTemplates.push({
   _id: faker.random.uuid(),
   'name.de': faker.internet.domainName(),
   language: faker.random.locale(),
   businessUnit: faker.random.uuid(),
   body: faker.lorem.paragraph()
  })
}

const findTemplates = allTemplates.map(item => item['name.de'])

const emailTemplate = {
   model: {
      findOne: params => {
         const found = allTemplates.find(item => params._id ? item._id === params._id : item['name.de'] === params['name.de'])
         const result = Object.assign({}, found, params)

         result.distinct = function (key) {
          return Promise.resolve(this[key])
         }
         
         return result
      }
   }
}

async function getTemplate (siteName) {
  const id = await emailTemplate.model.findOne({
    'name.de': siteName,
     language: 'en',
     businessUnit: '24ede462ad78fd0d4fd39dfa',
  }).distinct('_id')

  const body = await emailTemplate.model.findOne({
    '_id': id,
  }).distinct('body')

  return {
    id: id,
    body: body
  }
}

function replaceBody( body ) {
   return body.replace('one', 'two')
}

findTemplates.forEach(async templateName => {
   try {
     const template = await getTemplate( templateName )
     // You must not put await here because replace body does not return a Promise.
     const templateBody = replaceBody( template.body )
     console.log(templateBody.replace('string', 'another-string'))
   } catch (err) {
     console.err(`Error procesing template: ${templateName}: ${err}`)
   }
})

/**
 * Alternatively you can do:

Promise.all(findTemplates.map(async templateName => {
   const template = await getTemplate( templateName )
   // You must not put await here because replace body does not return a Promise.
   const templateBody = replaceBody( template.body )
   console.log(templateBody.replace('string', 'another-string'))
}).catch(err => console.err)
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/faker.min.js"></script>
```

So respect to your question: How can I use the replace function in my forEach async function? The answer is you can use replace as you do (but fix the line, and check what @t-j-crowder commented).

If the body is not string, then you should inspect what kind of object it is, and if it has a replace function (or not), and if this replace function returns (or not) a Promise.

Comment: thanks mauro! i already found the mistake. i had to add .toString to my template body. otherwise it not work. also i replace the forEach with a for loop, because in my for i can use await